# Difference between 'bad in poetry' and 'bad at poetry'?

Tags: vocabulary

I am confused between

> I am very bad in poetry

and

> I am very bad at poetry

Can anyone explain which one should I use.

Comment: This doesn't really answer your question, but you could always say: _I'm a terrible poet_. (If you can't find a preposition that sounds right, sometimes you can restructure the sentence and get rid of the preposition.)

Comment: The first could be talking about the antagonist of a poem. (Perhaps based on the person uttering the comment.) The second is talking about somebody who writes poetry.

Comment: Very good thought @JasonBassford, I’ve included this and cited you in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The preposition "at" or "in" changes the meaning a little bit.  Here is how:

---

### I am very bad in poetry

This is unusual.  This could mean:

> *I behave very badly* in *poetry class*.

But the listener should understand that "poetry" means **"poetry class"**, otherwise this is very unnatural.  Because this is such a specific situation, there would need to be **context**:

> "When do you find it hard to sit still and behave?" said the teacher.
>
> "I talk too much during music class," said Alice.
>
> "I misbehave during French class," said Bob.
>
> "I'm very bad in poetry," said Carol.

@Jason Bassford suggests it could also mean:

> *When I am portrayed in a poem*, I am *described as a very bad person*.
>
> "When songs and stories are told about me, they make me look like a hero," said Odysseus.
>
> "I am very bad in poetry," said the minotaur.

Either of the above is pretty obscure.

---

### I am very bad at poetry

This is very well understood to mean:

> I am very bad at **the art of** poetry.
>
> I am very bad at **the art of writing** poetry.
>
> I am very bad at **writing** poetry.
>
> I am very bad at **creating** poetry.

The use of "at" is so common in this kind of sentence, that "writing", "creating", or "the art of" --- all meaning **creating** --- can be dropped with no loss of meaning.

Dropping the participle is a little tricky, and just as in the first example, it requires **context**.

Here, you can drop "creating" because poetry is an art, so we assume you mean **creating** the art, not **consuming** (reading or reciting) it, or **doing other things** (publishing it, copying it from books, lifting books of it, engraving it in stone).   This is generally understood.

For any other usage besides the most common, you would need to *set the context* before dropping the word "creating".

> "What kind of text can you engrave?" said Alice the stonemason.
>
> **"I'm very bad at poetry,"** said Bob the engraver.
>
> "Me too," said Carol.

Some situations don't have **any** general understanding of what you mean. 
For example, this converation by itself is confusing:

> **"I'm very bad at furniture,"** said Alice.
>
> "Me too," said Bob.

But if you know this conversation is between two **woodworkers**, or two **painters**, or two **students studying the art of painting**, then you'll understand that they mean *building furniture*, *painting furniture*, or *painting pictures with furniture in them*.

Dropping the "action word" -- the participle -- requires context for the situation to make sense.  **It's only safe to drop the action word when the context is obvious.**